# What is the query limit for Session.executeAsync?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is there a limit enforced by Cassandra on how many queries can be submitted to `Session.executeAsync`? If I have a million select statements, I can call `executeAsync` in a `for` loop for all these statements. But I am unable to tell what's happening under the hood. Does Cassandra automatically batch the calls? Does it start failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the version of protocol used and number of connections opened to hosts. The V2 protocol supports 128 in-flight requests per connection, and V3 allows 32k requests per connection (default is 1000 although). You can configure it with [PoolingOptions.setMaxRequestsPerConnection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/#simultaneous-requests-per-connection) when you creating a cluster object.

But you can't simply multiple number of hosts by number of connections per host by number of in-flight requests and use this as max number - it's maximal theoretical limit, but it could be a situation when some nodes should handle more requests than other, and it's easy to go over the limit of particular node.  You can find more information about connection pooling in the [Java driver's documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/).

It's better to select some max number, and use the semaphore to not submit more requests than this limit. One example you can find [here](https://github.com/alexott/datastax-bootcamp-project/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/bootcamp/SessionLimiter.java).